# How can I merge a few rows in one column of a Tikz table?

Tags: tables

I wonder how to merge three consecutive rows of the first column in a table. I also need help in aligning the headers of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}


\newsavebox{\tablebox}
\definecolor{tablecolor}{named}{gray}

\NewEnviron{rndtable}[1]{%
  \addtolength{\extrarowheight}{1ex}%
  \rowcolors{2}{tablecolor!20}{tablecolor!40}%
  \sffamily%
  \newcommand{\header}[1]{%
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{%
      \cellcolor{tablecolor}\color{white}\bfseries##1}}
  \savebox{\tablebox}{%
    \begin{tabular}{#1}%
      \BODY%
    \end{tabular}}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip[rounded corners=1ex] (0,-\dp\tablebox) -- (\wd\tablebox,-\dp\tablebox) -- (\wd\tablebox,\ht\tablebox) -- (0,\ht\tablebox) -- cycle;
    \node at (0,-\dp\tablebox) [anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt]{\usebox{\tablebox}};
    \draw[tablecolor,very thick,rounded corners=1ex] (0,-\dp\tablebox) -- (\wd\tablebox,-\dp\tablebox) -- (\wd\tablebox,\ht\tablebox) -- (0,\ht\tablebox) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{center}
%\captionof{table}{Your caption here}

\begin{rndtable}{l p{2.5cm}}
  \header{Name} &
  \header{\parbox[t]{2cm}{Experience in Number of Years}} \\

    Ahmad & 7 Years \\
    Nadeem & 2 Years at UAF\\
  Nadeem & 1 Years at NTU\\
    Nadeem & 3 Years at GCU\\

    \end{rndtable}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you want to align the headers exactly?

Comment: vertically centered and left aligned

Comment: & also want to merge row number 2,3,4 of column 1

Comment: Then what should be the cell color after merging?

Comment: hmm, i think this should be same (dark or light) for the merging portion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dirty solution with a dirty result ;)

```
\documentclass[preview,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}


\newsavebox{\tablebox}
\definecolor{tablecolor}{named}{gray}

\NewEnviron{rndtable}[1]{%
  \addtolength{\extrarowheight}{1ex}%
  \rowcolors{2}{tablecolor!20}{tablecolor!40}%
  \sffamily%
  \newcommand{\header}[1]{%
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{%
      \cellcolor{tablecolor}\color{white}\bfseries##1}}
  \savebox{\tablebox}{%
    \begin{tabular}{#1}%
      \BODY%
    \end{tabular}}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip[rounded corners=1ex] (0,-\dp\tablebox) -- (\wd\tablebox,-\dp\tablebox) -- (\wd\tablebox,\ht\tablebox) -- (0,\ht\tablebox) -- cycle;
    \node at (0,-\dp\tablebox) [anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt]{\usebox{\tablebox}};
    \draw[tablecolor,very thick,rounded corners=1ex] (0,-\dp\tablebox) -- (\wd\tablebox,-\dp\tablebox) -- (\wd\tablebox,\ht\tablebox) -- (0,\ht\tablebox) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{center}
%\captionof{table}{Your caption here}

\begin{rndtable}{l p{2.5cm}}
  \header{Name} &
  \multicolumn{1}{C{2.5cm}}{\cellcolor{tablecolor}\textcolor{white}{\bfseries Experience in Number of Years}} \\

   \cellcolor{tablecolor!40}  & 7 Years \\
   \cellcolor{tablecolor!40}  & 2 Years at UAF\\
  \cellcolor{tablecolor!40}\multirow{-3}{*}{\parbox{1.5cm}{Ahmad Nadeem Nadeem}} & 1 Years at NTU\\
    Nadeem & 3 Years at GCU\\

    \end{rndtable}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]